# How to use alamofire with object mapper in Swift3 to map an array inside an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, alamofire

I have the following array which i am getting from Response:

How to get the value of operatingDay for each id in a single string separated by commas eg: Mon,Tue,Wed.... Currently I am getting the cashPointsOperatingDays in an array as a whole. How can I write the Swift3 code?

Using Object Mapper:

```
// MARK: Travel Shops Mapper
class GetTravelShopsResponse: Mappable {
    var message: String?
    var status: Int?
    var travelShopsData: [TravelShopsResponse]?
    var cashCollectionsDateTimeData: [CashCollectionsDateTime]?
    // var threeDayForecast: [TravelShopsResponse]?
    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        message    <- map["messages"]
        status    <- map["status"]
        travelShopsData <- map["data"]
    }
}

class TravelShopsResponse: Mappable {
    var messages: String?
    var name: String?
    var address: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var latitude: Float?
    var longitude: Float?
    var cashPointOperatingDays: [Any]?
    var locationid: String?
    required init?(map: Map) {
        mapping(map: map)
    }
    // Mappable
    func mapping(map: Map) {
        name  <- map["name"]
        address    <- map["address"]
        phoneNumber <- map["phoneNumber"]
        latitude       <- map["latitude"]
        longitude       <- map["longitude"]
        cashPointOperatingDays       <- map["cashPointOperatingDays"]
        locationid       <- map["id"]
    }
}
```

In my view Controller:

```
    //
import UIKit
import AlamofireObjectMapper
import Alamofire
class VPContactUsTravelShopsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var travelShopsTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var showallTravelShopsLabel: UILabel!
    var yourArray = [Any]()
    var nameArray = [Any]()
    var addressArray = [Any]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        getTravelShopsApiCall(URL:travelShopsURL!as URL)
    }
    // MARK: - UITableView delegates and datasources
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return yourArray.count
            }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "location", for: indexPath) as? TravelShopCustomCell {
            cell.travelShopName.text = self.nameArray[indexPath.row] as? String
            cell.addressTextView.text = self.addressArray[indexPath.row] as? String
            //var cashPointArray = cashPointOperatingDays["indexPath.item"]
            return cell
            } else {
            fatalError("Dequeueing SomeCell failed")
            }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
                    return 480
    }
    // MARK: - Get Contact Us API call
    func getTravelShopsApiCall(URL: URL) {
        Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<GetTravelShopsResponse>) in
                print(response.result.value!)
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    if !(response is NSNull) {
                        // optional is NOT NULL, neither NIL nor NSNull
                        guard let end = response.result.value else {
                            return
                        }
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //end = nullToNil(end.loginAuthenticationInfo?.accessToken)
                            self.yourArray = end.travelShopsData!
                            var dataArray = [Any]()
                            print(self.yourArray)
                            if let threeDayForecast = end.travelShopsData {
                                for forecast in threeDayForecast {
                                    self.nameArray.append(forecast.name as Any)
                                    self.addressArray.append(forecast.address as Any)
                                    dataArray.append(forecast.cashPointOperatingDays as Any)
                                    print(forecast.name as Any)
                                    print(forecast.address as Any)
                                    print(forecast.phoneNumber as Any)
                                    print(forecast.latitude as Any)
                                    print(forecast.longitude as Any)
                                    print(forecast.cashPointOperatingDays as Any)
                                                                                        }
                            }
//                            if let cashCollectionsDateTime = end.cashCollectionsDateTimeData {
//                                for operationDetails in cashCollectionsDateTime {
//                                    self.cashPointOperatingDaysArray.append(operationDetails.day as Any)
//                                    
//                                }
//                            }

                            self.travelShopsTableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else {
                        // null
                    }
                    break
                case .failure:
                    if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
                        print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
                    } else {
                        print("Unknown error: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                    }
                    break
                }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code on XCode or playground, so mind checking it.
I think this code snippet can be used in appending the array of cashPointOperatingDays.

```
for cashPointOperatingDay in cashPointOperatingDays {
    cashPointOperatingDays.append(cashPointOperatingDay)
}
```

This should be in your `TravelShopsResponse` class beneath the declaration of

```
 cashPointOperatingDays <- map["cashPointOperatingDays"]
```

And for retrieving, we can use in a tableView or collectionView `cellForRow` method:

```
var cashPointArray = cashPointOperatingDays["indexPath.item"]
let retrieveArray = cashPointArray["operatingDay"]
print(retrieveArray)
```

Again, please check it in your code.

Comment: it is showing error :
Value of type '[Any]?' has no member 'append'

Comment: @ cashPointOperatingDays.append(cashPointOperatingDay)

Comment: it would be better if you post the modified mapper file code.

Comment: Please give me your viewController file where you have initialized all the variables, I am on XCode now!

Comment: You could use pastebin and share the link on the comments or something pasting tool in the web, if you feel it's not vulnerable just in case.

Comment: Hello u there friend?

Comment: Thanks you so much... You seem to be busy at the moment. I gave up this question. I will try to sort out somehow.