# How to get the valueForKey?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following response from the json after parsing like this:
[Please click the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiUpG.png)

```
Array s: {
    endTimeAm = "";
    endTimePm = "22:00";
    operatingDay = Sun;
    startTimeAm = "07:00";
    startTimePm = "";
}
```

Please let me know how to get the value of "operatingDay" from the following?

```
print("Array s: \(cashPointOperatingDays[0])")
        guard let firstDict = cashPointOperatingDays[0] as? [[String: String]] else {
            return
        }
        print("First Dictionary: \(firstDict["operatingDay"])") //error showing line
    }
```

But i am getting

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String : String]]' with an index of type 'String'" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Array is actually not an Array but Dictionary.

```
print("JSON object  s: \(cashPointOperatingDays[0])")
        guard let firstDict = cashPointOperatingDays[0] as? [String: String] else {
            return
        }
        print("First Dictionary: \(firstDict["operatingDay"])") //error showing line
```

Comment: See again my answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743257/how-to-use-alamofire-with-object-mapper-in-swift3-to-map-an-array-inside-an-arra